# Will VB.NET and C# CIL look the same?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

When I build my .NET application, what will the assembly contain? CIL?
And second question, when doing the same thing in different .NET langugaes, will the CIL be exactly the same or same in the terms of similarity that works exactly the same way?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they won't be the same.
VB.Net uses helper methods in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll instead of many IL instructions to achieve VB semantics.
This includes equality (`"" = Nothing`), certain string operations, and I don't remember what else.

Comment: I would have to restrain myself if I ever saw `"" = Nothing"` in code

Comment: @msarchet: In VB.Net, they're considered equal.

Comment: @msarchet, Amen! String.IsNullOrEmpty() look so right in both languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can not guarantee that VB.Net and C# will boil down to the same IL, but provided you wrote functionally identical routines, the IL could produce the same result.

Answer (score 1):

For many methods, the compiled result (CIL) will be the same.

There are however constructs in either language that are solved differently, or just not possible. This can never result in the same instructions.

Answer (score 1):

All languages based on .net compile to ILCode (Intermidiate Language). The resulting ILCode will be the same if done the same, so for example, member access on an object will always be the same. However, there are features that don't have representations in other languages, so it is possible that ILCode can't be expressed in that language, as it uses a feature not available in that language. Referencing the assembly is still possible though.

Answer (score 1):

If the code works the same way, then barring compiler errors you can guarantee the IL generated will work the same way.

However, it's up to the compiler how it implements your code, and as VB and C# use different compilers there's no guarantee they'll have implemented your code as the same IL.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, all .NET applications are compiled to **[CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)**

2), No, the IL won't always look exactly the same between different .NET language.  They'll likely be similar for similar source code constructs, but each language has subtle differences in how things are implemented so the IL ends up looking slightly different (but often behaving in a relatively similar fashion).